# Combine two formulas/functions in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Trying to combine two formulas in one cell.  I want to do a math function followed by formatting the cell to text and only display 3 decimal spaces. This is the formula I attempted: =CONCATENATE(B8*(1+$J$3)+($K$3),"|",TEXT(N8,"0.000"))

Comment: What cell are you entering this in?  And what's the problem?

Comment: The formula you have provided seems to be working fine but your requirement is unclear. What type of Math function you want to do with the concatenate'd Cell ? Do you have example outputs?

Comment: Example input and output would help. But what about something like: =round((B8*(1+J3)+(K3),3)&"|"&N8 - not tested but might give you some direction as I can't tell what is where.

Comment: [ calculate `B8*(1+$J$3)+($K$3)' > change this value to number > display it in "0.000" format ] Is this what you intent to do ?

Comment: I am entering this formula in cell N8

Comment: p_phidot, yes this is my intent

Answer (score 0):

You stated in the comments that you are entering this into cell N8, you can't reference the cell you're working in like that.

Try it this way around:

=TEXT((B8*(1+$J$3)+($K$3)),"0.000")&"|"